# Body text after latex title page not showing, Rmarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, page-title

I have successfully been able to add a latex title page to my Rmarkdown file, but the rest of the document doesn't appear. Here is my YAML:

```
---

output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: title.tex
---
```

I haven't changed anything else in the Rmarkdown file, it has the standard text starting with: This is an Rmarkdown document etc. I include my title.tex file:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    
    \includegraphics{UCTLogoLong.jpg} 
        \vspace*{2cm}
        
        \textbf {\Huge Applied Spatial Data Analysis} % MAIN TITLE
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        
        {\LARGE Assignment 1} % SUBTITLE
        \vspace{1cm}
        
        \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}} 
        
        {\LARGE Geostatistics}
        \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}} 
        \vspace{1cm}
        
        {\Large NAME }  % AUTHOR
        
        {\Large STUDENT NUMBER}
        \vspace{1cm}
        
        \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{statslogo.png} 
         
    \vspace{0.2cm}
        
        Department of Statistical Sciences\\
        University of Cape Town\\
        South Africa\\
        \today
        
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

I am relatively new to Rmarkdown and have no idea why the standard Rmarkdown text isn't showing in knitted pdf. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that with the `\begin{document}...\end{document}` you tell latex that it should ignore everything after that. Instead you could issue the content of the title page `\AtBeginDocument{...}`

`title.tex`:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\AtBeginDocument{

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck} 
        \vspace*{2cm}
        
        \textbf {\Huge Applied Spatial Data Analysis} % MAIN TITLE
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        
        {\LARGE Assignment 1} % SUBTITLE
        \vspace{1cm}
        
        \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}} 
        
        {\LARGE Geostatistics}
        \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}} 
        \vspace{1cm}
        
        {\Large John Doe }  % AUTHOR
        
        {\Large something}
        \vspace{1cm}
        
        \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck} 
         
    \vspace{0.2cm}
        
        Department of Statistical Sciences\\
        University of Cape Town\\
        South Africa\\
        \today
        
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage
}
```

Furthermore, I had to remove the empty line in

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: title.tex
---
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I realise that my name is in this question and would prefer to keep that private - I am going to edit the question so that my name doesn't appear etc.

Comment: @anemone19 You're welcome! I replaced the name with something generic in the answer+image. Please note that the name will remain visible in the history of the post. If you want to completely remove it, you would need to persuade a mod to redact the history.